# Is there a way to rename files downloaded with wget when using -i to download from a list of links?

Tags: awk, sed, download, wget, xargs

I have a large text file of links that I want to mass download using wget, but the file names are getting extra junk added to them from the url and I want to prevent that. The urls are broadly formatted as `https://(website)/(filename.json.gz)?&Expires=(random numbers)&Signature=(long string of random characters)&Key-Pair-Id=(more random characters)` and when downloaded using wget, the &Expires and &Signature sections of the url are appended to the filename. If I enter each url into a browser to manually download the files one at a time, it gets saved under the filename in the url without any extra information, and this is the behavior I want to replicate using wget.

As far as I can tell, the -O option is the only way to rename files as you download them, and it doesn't seem to have any use for me in this situation (will just write all the downloaded files to a single document). I've been using `find . -depth -name "*.json.gz*" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; mv -- "$f" "${f%.json.gz*}.json.gz"' \;` to mass rename files after each batch of links finishes downloading, but if there's a way to avoid this extra step I would definitely like to find it so I can simplify my process a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know way to combine `-i` and `-O` in `wget`, however some servers do send [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) response header, which inform what should be name of file, you might view response headers using `wget` following way

```
wget -S --spider http://www.example.com
```

If your server do issue `Content-Disposition` then you might use them following way

```
wget --content-disposition -i urls.txt
```

If server does not provide them, then I suggest you to write simple `bash` script which would for each line in your file: read URL, derive filename from URL, call `wget`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a solution that's only slightly janky. In case anyone else has a similar issue here's what I ended up settling on:

```
cat link-list | sed 's/.*\(2023.*.json.gz\).*/wget -nc -O \1 -P "\/destination\/for\/files\/" &/' | xargs -I% echo % > wget-commands
```

This isn't ideal, as it relies on all of the filenames starting with "2023", but for the set of files I'm working with now this is fine, and it shouldn't be too hard to adjust if I run into different naming conventions later.

I was experimenting with using awk to remove the section of the url before the filename and sed to remove the section after the filename like so:

```
cat link-list awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed 's/\(^.*.json.gz\).*/\1/' > filenames
```

This successfully isolated the filename from the rest of the link, and seems like it would be more robust than relying on the content of the filename since the filename will always follow the last forward slash in the url, but for some reason this awk command seems to break when it's run through xargs, and I couldn't figure out a way to turn the output into a wget command without xargs. I would expect the following to have the same output as the previous example, but when I run it the output only has the section after the filename trimmed off, and it appears as if awk didn't do anything at all.

```
cat link-list | xargs -I% sh -c "echo '%' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed 's/\(^.*.json.gz\).*/\1/'" > filenames
```

The solution I found without awk works for now, but if anyone has any insight into why awk stopped behaving the way I expected when used within xargs I would still appreciate it, if for no other reason than to satisfy my own curiosity. I'm still relatively new to both awk and sed, so I imagine there's something fundamental I'm missing here and I'd like to use the opportunity to learn a bit.

Comment: please consider posting question with `awk` tag in order to get relevant answers, this should make it easier to `awk`-using users to find it